# biblatex prints editor twice in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

MWE

Bib:

```
@inproceedings{Gossart:10,
author = {Gossart, D and Meskens, N and Guinet, A},
editor = {Camarinha-Matos, L M and Boucher, X and Afsarmanesh, H},
title = {{Strategic and Tactical Bed Management in Belgium and France}},
booktitle = {Collaborative Networks for a Sustainable World},
year = {2010},
address = {Berlin},
publisher = {Springer},
pages = {243--250}
}
```

code:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, index=totoc]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, sorting=ynt, bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex} % Keller 11.1.
\addbibresource{library.bib}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Variables influencing on the tactical decision level}\label{chap3}
blablabla
\autocite{Gossart:10}
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=nyt]
\printbibliography
\end{refcontext}
\end{document}
```

output:

```
Bibliography
Gossart, D., Meskens, N., & Guinet, A. (2010). Strategic and Tactical Bed Management in Belgium and France (L. M. Camarinha-Matos, X. Boucher, & H. Afsarmanesh, Eds.). In L. M. Camarinha-Matos, X. Boucher, & H. Afsarmanesh (Eds.), Col- laborative networks for a sustainable world, Berlin, Springer.
```

Why on earth do the editors show up twice here?

Comment: When I compile you example, I get the expected output. Maybe delete the temporary files and try again...

Comment: I also get the expected output, but I think there was a bug in an older version that would show the editors twice. Make sure your TeX system is fully up to date. (I have `biblatex-apa` 2020/08/28 v9.14)

Comment: I trashed every temporary but the problem persists. Where do I find out about my biblatex-apa version? I'm using Texshop on MacOS. Biber says V 2.14. Should I include the logs of biblatex?

Comment: I now found a similar question regarding this topic (searched for "twice" and "double" but not "duplicating" before posting). Flagged my own question now as duplicate. I think that's it. But still struggling with finding out my biblatex-apa version and how to update it.

Comment: You'll find it in the .log file or the documentation of biblatex-apa installed on your system.  You can update with TeX Live Utility.

Comment: The generic answer to how you can update your TeX distribution is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864, but there are some pitfalls (TeX Live and MacTeX can only be updated for a year, after that you need to install a new version to stay up-to-date; the current version would be TeX live/MacTeX 2020)

Comment: Took me a while... I have biblatex-apa v9.6. Luckily I had MacTeX 2000 installed and could use Tex Live Utility to update. MWE compile was successful. Also tested the full document. At the first glance the updates didn't break anything else.

Comment: As everything is settled now, should I delete my question or should I let it persist as a link to the prior one which I wasn't able to find?